# What substance can be used to kill all pathogens?

Tags: safety, diseases, cleaning, parasites, hygiene

What can I use to disinfect an area after animals like dogs, cats and chickens were present? I'd like to know solution for small (doghouse) and bigger areas (room size). It'll be used for animals, but I'd like it to be safe for humans as well.

I heard that the most complicated part is destroying microscopic eggs that have shells made of chitin as chitin isn't soluble in most solutions. Only the strongest acids can do that.

For instance, what do people use to guarantee destruction of parasitic eggs in animal cages or in a dog house?

Comment: can you please add some information about what animals lived there,some information about the size of the area you want to disinfect and some information about what the area will be used for in the future.

Comment: @trond hansen dogs, cats, chickens. Id like to know solution for small (doghouse) and bigger areas (room size). Itll be used for animals, but id like it to be safe for humans as well.

Comment: i will try to make an answer in the weekend,most likely you will need a combination of chemicals to fully disinfect the area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you use any of the chemicals i mention here please READ THE INSTRUCTIONS AND WARNINGS ON THE PRODUCTS.

To dissinfect a small area like a doghouse or a cage that you know are infected with parasites you can use potassium permanganate dissolved in water,potassium permanganate is a very strong oxidizer that is effective against bacteria,virus,fungi and parasites and their eggs.

Potassium permanganate will color anything purple but it can be neutralized with hydrogen peroxide an other strong oxidizer,hydrogen peroxide too will dissinfect the area and it is effective against the same pathogens as potassium permanganate.

WARNING NEVER MIX DRY POTASSIUM PERMANGANATE AND HYDROGEN PEROXIDE(it is hypergolic rocket fuel and nasty things will happen).

For dissinfection of room sized areas you can use chlorine(common bleach) in water,chlorine is effective against bacteria,virus,fungi,parasites and the eggs of parasites.

An other thing you can use to dissinfect room sized areas is ammonia in water but to use this the area needs to be well ventilated as this has a very strong smell,ammonia is effective against bacteria,virus,fungi and parasites including their eggs,ammonia dissolves fat.

WARNING NEVER MIX CHLORINE AND AMMONIA(the result is toxic gasses and chloramines).

And last you can use hydrogen peroxide to dissinfect room sized areas but you need to be aware it can bleach paint and take away colors of many materials,hydrogen peroxide breaks down into water and oxygen whitin hours so it is safe to use indoors where you live.

All of the chemicals mentioned here will be safe for people and pets when it is fully dry/outgassing is over,in less than 24 hrs.

Sources.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_permanganate

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia

Comment: +1 rocket science